# Proxy server in Java: Not able to send a response back to the client

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I'm trying to write a piece of code to implement a proxy server. However, I am not able t send data back to the client as the response appears as follows.

The Response shows a normal response and a few responses come up later which says URI is too large.

```
HTTP/1.1 414 Request-URI Too Large
Date: Sun, 01 Sep 2013 14:52:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 325
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request-URI Too Large</h1>
<p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.1.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

The code is as follows.

```
package ownproxy;

/**
 *
 * @author mklrjv
 */
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class InterceptionProxy2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listening = true;
        int port = 1234;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Port Error");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        while (listening) {
            new ProxyThread2(serverSocket.accept()).start();
        }
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}

class ProxyThread2 extends Thread {

    private Socket socket = null;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32768;

    public ProxyThread2(Socket socket) {
        super("ProxyThread2");
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        PrintWriter outGoing = null;
        try {
            outGoing = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader inComing = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String incomingRequest;
            String url = "";
            String request = "";
            String response = "";
            //Take the incoming request
            char[] buf = new char[1000000];
            inComing.read(buf);
            request = new String(buf);
            //Create a new socket for connecting to destination server
            Socket connSocket = new Socket("localhost", 80);
            PrintWriter pOut = new PrintWriter(connSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader pIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connSocket.getInputStream()));
            //Put data into the new socket(to the apache server) and receive its output
            pOut.print(request);
            pIn.read(buf);
            response = new String(buf);
            System.out.println(response);
            //Put data back into the original client socket
            outGoing.write(response);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProxyThread2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            outGoing.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what is causing the 414 error.  If you are not using a web browser on your proxy but are manually sending a GET request (or some other non-http request), a bug in your code (see below) may cause more than 8196 characters to be in the GET request, which is the default limit for Apache.

You should change your code so that it is creating strings with the String(buffer, offset, length) constructor, which uses the amount of the bytes read, not the full buffer, which probably contains many NULL values if the request and response are short.  Also, you should consider flushing the output back to the proxy client.  Here's your code with those changes

```
public void run() {
  PrintWriter outGoing = null;
  try {
     outGoing = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
     BufferedReader inComing = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
     String incomingRequest;
     String url = "";
     String request = "";
     String response = "";
     //Take the incoming request
     char[] buf = new char[100000];
     int bytesRead = inComing.read(buf);
     request = new String(buf, 0, bytesRead);
     //Create a new socket for connecting to destination server
     Socket connSocket = new Socket("localhost", 10003);
     PrintWriter pOut = new PrintWriter(connSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

     //Reader for response from destination server
     BufferedReader pIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connSocket.getInputStream()));
     //Put data into the new socket(to the apache server) and receive its output
     pOut.print(request);
     pOut.flush();
     bytesRead = pIn.read(buf);

     if(bytesRead > 0) {
        response = new String(buf, 0, bytesRead);
     }

     System.out.println(response);
     //Put data back into the original client socket
     outGoing.write(response);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(ProxyThread2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } finally {
     outGoing.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write an HTTP proxy like this. You need two threads, one in each direction, that both just copy bytes. The reason is HTTP keep-alive. You can't tell where the end the requester the response is it huot parsing headers, chunks, etc. amd it all gets too hard.